# How do i send HTML email containing dynamic link via JAVA

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send a dynamic link via email with the following code.

```
Message messageSSL = new MimeMessage(session);
int hash=1000;

String content="<a href=\"www.abc.com/activation?hash="+i+"\">click here</a>";

messageSSL.setContent(content, "text/html");
```

However, i have failed to generate a dynamic link.The output in the mail is in the plain text format.

Output (In the mail):

```
click here
```

Even though, the following code works and generates a link called "click here".

```
String content="<a href=\"www.abc.com\">click here</a>";
```

Thanks!!

Comment: It isn't a duplicate question, please read the question completely.

Comment: Could it be that you're simply viewing a correctly formatted email in plaintext? (i.e., change format for the client)

Comment: @Keyser Can you explain little further?

Comment: What mail server are you using?  What mail reader are you using?  What do you see if you use the "view source" feature in your mail reader to view the raw MIME text of the message?  Does it help if you put "http://" at the beginning of your URL?

Comment: @Bill the issue has been resolved, issue was due to the backward slash. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with backward slash. We should be using forward slash in urls. Please change and try it.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Commons Email library has some useful classes that take care of the low-level details for stuff like making HTML email work properly. Check it out:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/

Answer (score 0):

can you please enclose the link by html tag and try once.

```
 String content="<html><body><a href='www.abc.com\\activation?hash="+i+"\">click here</a> </body></html>";
```

i am using same library and working fine for me.

please check below thread
[How Can I put a HTML link Inside an email body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492869/how-can-i-put-a-html-link-inside-an-email-body)